# Swapping values in variable in R?

Tags: r

I am new to using R, and I am trying to solve a basic issue. So I’m reading some data off an excel sheet, and each of the columns on the sheet corresponds to a test item (each item was scored true or false, 1 or 2). I have identified and subsetted the specific columns/items that I am interested in using this function:

```
CD <- paste("items",c(1,5,11,13,17,20,21,23,28,31,34,47,59,65,72,77,82,86), sep="")
```

Here is what I would like to do: For some of the columns/items, I would like to change all of the scores of 2 to scores of 1. Likewise, I would like to change all of the scores of 1 to scores 2. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Where are scores?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the columns update the values:

```
# example data
set.seed(1); myData <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:2, 25, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5))
myData
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  1  1  1  2  1
# 2  2  1  1  2  1
# 3  1  1  1  2  1
# 4  1  2  1  2  1
# 5  2  2  1  1  1

# columns we want to update
CD <- paste0("X", 1:3)

# loop and update
myData[ CD ] <- lapply(myData[ CD ], function(i) c(2:1)[ i ])

myData
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  2  2  2  2  1
# 2  1  2  2  2  1
# 3  2  2  2  2  1
# 4  2  1  2  2  1
# 5  1  1  2  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the values from selected columns from 3. `3 - 2` would give you 1 and `3 - 1` gives 2. If the data is called `data`, you may do -

```
data[CD] <- 3 - data[CD]
```